# weboptimization css bundle not found (404)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, optimization, webforms

I have made an Asp.Net webforms website in C# using the .net framework 4.6.1.
The website works perfectly but when I try to optimize the CSS load using the weboptimization component **I get a 404 from the css url request**.

Please note that I have also the js bundle that works perfectly.

in the .aspx page I have in the head:

```
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/stylesheets" />
```

the bundle.config is in the root of the site structure and its content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bundles version="1.2">
  <styleBundle path="~/stylesheets">
    <include path="~/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <include path="~/css/style.css" />
    <include path="~/css/custom.css" />
  </styleBundle>
</bundles>
```

Inspecting the network request I see that the request for stylesheets
[image]

[image]

where base-site is instead the js bundle

Global.asax file:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
    ...
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
        <pages enableEventValidation="true">
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
            <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
          </namespaces>
          <controls>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
          </controls>
        </pages>
        ...
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
      <remove name="BundleModule"/>
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule"/>
    </modules>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
```

I have an identical website with the same web.config, same routing configuration with *EnableFriendlyUrls(True)* where the CSS bundle is correctly provided.

- It doesn't work both local on VS2017 and on the production server.
- There is no folder or other pages named "stylesheets"
- The CSS files are well-formed
- I've tried also with a single CSS file, but I get always a 404.
- The routing for all the other pages and JS bundle works fine

**Why the CSS bundle doesn't work?** 
Is there something I can do to understand where is the issue?

Comment: May it be related to relative/absolute path issue?

Comment: @ahmet I've checked almost a million of times letter by letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests, I have found that every time I make a change in the css bundle.config file I have to close and restart Visual Studio. 
Restarting IIS Express is not enough.

On the production server, I have to stop and start again the website, recycling the application pool.

Comment: and I can say that the restart of app-pool and website not always works... (cache on my browser is disabled, so I'm not taking cached bundle)